# Why is my code not defining render in my HTML5 game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my first year at programming and I'm following this [HTML5 Game Development Series on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHnog5_EZ_f30-4YkdKCYgjopBog7dZ6F).

**I'm following line by line with his code and my code is still producing errors.**

The console log is saying the following: `game.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined`

The goal is for the *black* square to be able to move with input keys and for random *yellow* coins to be generated. The coins are being generated, but I can no longer move the black square.

**There are no problems in *index.php*, I will show my code for game.js**

```
width = 400;
height = 400;

var FPS = 60;
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var g = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x = 50;
var y = 50;

coins = [];

var player = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  speed: 3,
  tick: function() {
    if(Key.up && this.y > 0) this.y-= this.speed;
    if(Key.down && this.y < height - 20) this.y+= this.speed;
    if(Key.left && this.x > 0) this.x-= this.speed;
    if(Key.right && this.x < width - 20) this.x+= this.speed;
  },
  render: function() {
    g.fillStyle = "black";
    g.fillRect(this.x,this.y,20,20);
  }
};

var Key = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
};

addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  switch(keyCode) {
    case 38: // up
      Key.up = true;
      break;

    case 40: // down
      Key.down = true;
      break;

    case 37: // left
      Key.left = true;
      break;

    case 39: // right
      Key.right = true;
      break;
  }
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  switch(keyCode) {
    case 38: // up
      Key.up = false;
      break;

    case 40: // down
      Key.down = false;
      break;

    case 37: // left
      Key.left = false;
      break;

    case 39: // right
      Key.right = false;
      break;
  }
}, false);

function Coin(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = 8;
  this.render = function() {
    g.fillStyle = "yellow";
    g.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
  };

  this.tick = function() {

  };
}

function createCoins(amount) {
  var i = 0;
  while(i < amount) {
    i++;
    coins.push(new Coin(Math.random()*width,Math.random()*height));
  }
}

function renderCoins() {
  var i = 0;
  while(i < coins.length) {
    i++;
    coins[i].render();
  }
}


function render() {

  renderCoins();
  createCoins(20);
  g.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  player.render();
}

function tick() {
 player.tick();
}

setInterval(function() {
  render();
  tick();
}, 1000/FPS );
```

[image: Coins Visual Aid]

Comment: Inside of your renderCoins, swap the two lines in the while loop, meaning put "i++" after your render call.

Comment: @ndugger I did your code. The black box moves around with key inputs fine, but the coins now disappear. There are no errors in the console log when I do your code.

Comment: You are clearing the whole rectangle after you draw the coins but before you draw you player. The clear rect should go above the coin drawing

Comment: @karina Is this what you're meaning: `function render() {
  
  g.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  renderCoins();
  createCoins(20);
  player.render();
}`

Comment: That should work OK. Except that it will create 20 new coins every time... Is that what you want?

Comment: @karina No. I want only one set of 20 coins. This new code creates new coins until they fill the entire canvas. Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Well then you better take createCoins out of the render function. Perhaps just run it once before you start you interval

Comment: @karina Thanks this worked! Do you want to post your comment as the answer or do you want me to post this comment as a community wiki?

Comment: I can post it as an answer once I get to a computer.  Yay answering on the mobile app :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things:

As per @nduggers comment you need to put your i++ after your array accessor in renderCoins.  You are getting `game.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined` because you are accessing an invalid index on the very last iteration of that loop

Next in your render function

```
function render() {
  renderCoins();     //you are rendering coins that have not been initted yet
  createCoins(20);   //you will create 20 new coins every time you render
  g.clearRect(0,0,width,height);   //you are clearing any coins you just rendered
  player.render();    //you are now rendering just the player on an empty canvas
}
```

So you need to create your coins outside the render function, otherwise you will create 20 new coins every render.  Next you need to move your clear rect to the top of the render function.  then render coins and render player.  then all should be good.